# CCavenue integration in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, ccavenue

Actually I have integrated CCAvenue JSP_Kit to my Lifreay portal 6.2. Till payment every thing is working properly that means after filling all the payment details and submitting no error is coming. But we are getting a response as null.

Below is the code of ReponseHandler.jsp.

encResp is coming null after payment or after cancel the request.

```
<%
String workingKey = "working key"; //32 Bit Alphanumeric Working Key should be entered here so that data can be decrypted.
String encResp= request.getParameter("encResp");
AesCryptUtil aesUtil=new AesCryptUtil(workingKey);
String decResp = aesUtil.decrypt(encResp);
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decResp, "&");
Hashtable hs=new Hashtable();
String pair=null, pname=null, pvalue=null;
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
pair = (String)tokenizer.nextToken();
if(pair!=null) {
StringTokenizer strTok=new StringTokenizer(pair, "=");
pname=""; pvalue="";
if(strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
pname=(String)strTok.nextToken();
if(strTok.hasMoreTokens())
pvalue=(String)strTok.nextToken();
hs.put(pname, pvalue);
}
}
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the portal world you typically don't have access to the full and original HttpServletRequest. You *can* get access to it by calling

```
origRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalHttpServletRequest( 
                            PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest());
```

This, of course, means that you're somewhat outside of the spec, however if you really need to communicate through servlet parameters, that might be your only option. I'd also recommend to add this code to a better testable/maintainable location - e.g. inside the Java Portlet class.

[Here's the PortalUtil interface](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil.html).